# Google amp component amp-list load more did not work

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

I had activate the AMP experiment amp-list-load-more, but it did not work

my page https://www.airtonews.com/amp/

```js
<amp-list src="data/list.json"
          load-more="manual"
          load-more-bookmark="next"
          binding="no"
          width="auto"
          height="300"
          layout="fixed-height">
    <amp-list-load-more load-more-button>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            <div class="url-entry">
                <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
            </div>
        </template>
        <button>
            See More
        </button>
    </amp-list-load-more>
</amp-list>
```

how to make it work? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [load-more-button](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list#load-more-button) documentation:

> An `<amp-list-load-more>` element with the `load-more-button`
>   attribute that a button with the `load-more-clickable` attribute,
>   which shows up at the end of the list (for the manual load-more) if
>   there are more elements to be loaded. Clicking on this element will
>   trigger a fetch to load more elements from the **url** contained in
>   the `load-more-src` field or the field of the data returned
>   corresponding to the load-more-bookmark attribute.

Example:

```
<amp-list load-more src="https://www.load.more/" ...>
  <div load-more-button>
    See More /* My custom see more button */
  </div>
</amp-list>
```

Include the `src` attribute in your `<amp-list load-more>` element. Try and check the implementation above.